# Scraping a site with BeautifulSoup doesn't get all entries

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to learn more about scraping sites, and tie it in with automating tasks. I have been using BeautifulSoup4 and for the most part it works like I would have thought it would. I have tested it on a few sites, and it hit a point where it no longer works 100%. I am trying to scrape https://runelite.net/plugin-hub for all of the names of the plugins. This is the code I am using to do this:

```
 import requests
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 import time
 url = "https://runelite.net/plugin-hub/"

 response=requests.get(url)

 i = 0
 # check if successful request
 if response.status_code == 200:
    # parse the HTML content of the page
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

    # find all elements with class 'col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 mb-2'
    col_md_4_elements = soup.find_all(class_='col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 mb-2')
    # loop through the elements
    for col_md_4 in col_md_4_elements:
    
        # find all the cards
        card = col_md_4.find(class_='card')
        if card:
            # find the card body
            card_body = card.find(class_='card-body d-flex align-self-stretch')

            if card_body:
                # find card title
                card_title = card_body.find('h5', class_='card-title')

                if card_title:
                    plugin_name = card_title.text.strip()
                    i = i +1
                    print(card_title)
                    time.sleep(200/1000)

print('there is a total of ' + str(i) + ' plugins')
```

It does what I expect - as in return the names of 'most' plugins - though, the script does miss some. For example "Spirit Tree Map" does not appear in the output, and the counter (i) returns a total of 821 plugins over the 832 plugins that the site mentions. I can't see any issues with Beautiful Soup not loading all of the page's details, as it loads plugins that appear lower, and the structure of the HTML does not seem to change. I tried adding a time.sleep(), in case it was hopping over some parts, but the results are still the same. Can you suggest a solution for this? I imagine I'm missing something very simple.

Comment: I think you mean **scraping** sites.

Comment: Spirit Tree Map isn't in the HTML source, it must be added dynamically by JavaScript.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks! I switched over to selenium and it's all accounted for now. Is there a reason behind why this happens for some entries and not others?

Comment: Actually - I read the linked question, I understand it now :)